# Is it possible to create an XML type element with name that is not equal to class name?

Tags: java, jaxb

Currently i am using @XmlType(name = "MyClass") for a class, named "MyClass". Is it possible to rename a class without changing a name of xml element (basically, i don't want to affect client-server contract)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all the annotations allow you to override the name in cases where the default is derived from the class, field, or property names.

The following classes would map to the same XML and schema.

**Foo**

In this class all the type and element names are based on the default naming rules.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

   private String fooProp;

}
```

**Bar**

This class maps to the same XML and schema as the `Foo` class.  To do this we have had to provide all the names as the default names would not match those from `Foo`.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="foo")
@XmlType(name="foo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Bar {

    @XmlElement(name="fooProp")
    private String barProp;

}
```